# Accidentally disabled touchpad on Lenovo Thinkpad T15 - can't reenable

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I almost dropped my laptop, but I caught it! However, in catching it, I pressed a *lot* of buttons simultaneously. Now, my touchpad isn't working, and I have no idea how to reenable it.

I've found lots of similar questions, but the solutions don't work for me:

1. Most questions about the Lenovo T15 laptop revolves around Windows, and I use Ubuntu.
2. Must Ubuntu-related answers involve opening the mouse settings. My mouse and touchpad settings are fully enabled, so I suspect it's something hardware-related.
3. Some answers state that there's a keyboard shortcut with an icon of a mousepad - I don't have that icon!

Any help is welcome. This is really annoying.

Comment: 3: yes there is an Fn + functionkey combo to enable it. Probably Fn + F5.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but I left it running for a few hours, and now it works. I really didn't do anything. But maybe this can help someone in the future: Just let it run unattended for a few hours - maybe it helps :-)